# How to turn SVG text inwards

Tags: html, svg, navigation

Hey I am new to svg formats and stuff but I need to turn text on the outside of this circle:
[image]

I need the text around it to be positioned like this:
[image]

This is the html code I've been trying to use:

```html
    <svg viewbox="0 100 300 500">
            <path id="circle" fill='red' d="M80,300a70,70 0 1,0 140,0a70,70 0 1,0 -140,0"/>
            <a class='NavPages' href="google.com">
                <text id="Henosis" dy="15" dx="320">
                    <textPath xlink:href="#circle">
                        Henosis
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </a>
            <a class='NavPages' href="">
                <text id="Henosis" dy="15" dx="150">
                    <textPath xlink:href="#circle">
                        Dispaaru
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </a>
            <a class='NavPages' href="">
                <text id="Henosis" dy="15" dx="">
                    <textPath xlink:href="#circle">
                        Expansion
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </a>
        </svg>
```

Btw the different words are supposed to be hyperlinks, can someone please help me understand how to fix the orientation of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do it I reversed the path id="circle" by changing the d attribute from `d="M80,300a70,70 0 1,0 140,0a70,70 0 1,0 -140,0"` to `d="M80,300a70,70 0 1 1 140,0 a70,70 0 1 1 -140,0"`

In order to reverse the path I've changed the 5th parameter (sweep-flag) of the arcs `a` from 0 to 1

> a rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag dx dy

The sweep-flag determines the direction to draw the arc.

```html
<svg viewbox="60 200 200 200">
   
        <path id="circle" fill='red' d="M80,300a70,70 0 1 1 140,0 a70,70 0 1 1 -140,0"/>
        <a class='NavPages' href="google.com">
            <text id="Henosis" dy="15" dx="320">
                <textPath xlink:href="#circle">
                    Henosis
                </textPath>
            </text>
        </a>
        <a class='NavPages' href="">
            <text id="Henosis" dy="15" dx="150">
                <textPath xlink:href="#circle">
                    Dispaaru
                </textPath>
            </text>
        </a>
        <a class='NavPages' href="">
            <text id="Henosis" dy="15" dx="">
                <textPath xlink:href="#circle">
                    Expansion
                </textPath>
            </text>
        </a>

</svg>
```

Observation: I've changed the viewBox of the svg element. You can use your viewBox.